# People tagging in photos in Linux

Tags: linux, photos, pictures

I have recently started (once again) to fiddle around with Linux, currently running Kubuntu 12.04. I have a rather big library of Photos, a lot of which have people tags set up in Windows Live Gallery.

Is there any way of getting these to work in Linux? As far as I understand there's no "proper" standard for doing these but MS did document the way they're doing it ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719905(v=vs.85).aspx ). So far I have been unable to find any program that at least remotely replicates that functionality (save people tags in the files' metadata so they won't get lost), not even speaking about compatibility to my existing tags.

Am I missing anything? Is there some exotic plugin for Gwenview, some fork of Digikam, some hack of Shotwell or some config file of F-Spot that could be used to get this to work?

So far the Linux approach seems to be to ignore that feature as it has not been properly standardized... Which is understandable from a technical point of view but very unsatisfying from a user's perspective :-/.

Answer (score 1):

According to the status of [this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=271030), there should already be compatability in DigiKam for Windows Live Gallery faces, and it is being tested. I think you will just have to wait, or, if you don't mind using untested code, [this](http://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=61791) patch here should work.